# File of 2 GB fails when uploading from client machine in ASP.NET webform using FileUpload control

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, webforms

I have web form application where we upload file using FileUpload folder. So far it was working fine when loading file around 1 Gig.  Now the file size has increased and reached beyond 2 Gig.  During the file upload the application fails with the error
**HTTP Error 400.0 - Bad Request. ASP.NET detected invalid characters in the URL**

I searched the net and found that ASP.NET 4.5 set a limit to file upload upto 2 GB. Now I am looking for the solution. Loading file greater than a gig should be norm by now.

I don't know if upgrading the app to ASP.Net webform or MVC 6 would resolve the issue. I searched the net but did not get the clear picture.

**Update:**
Beside the accepted answer below. I found some other options or work around

1. Directly upload the file to a Azure Storage Container which could be a staging folder through Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer.   Then in the program get the list of the blobs from the Stage container so user can select the file to upload. Just get the name of the file and then copy the file from stage to container where you want to store the file.  (This option may not work for all but work perfectly for me and meets the business requirements)
2. Load the file through browser using javascript.
   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/quickstart-blobs-javascript-browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I mean, really, for anything beyond say 100 megs, then you need to adopt a ajax file up-loader.

This will thus not make user's think the browser is frozen, and more important they will see a progress bar.

These up-loaders thus up-load in chunks, and thus allow un-limited file size up-loads.

There are quite a few free up-loaders (I think one is file pond).

And they work even with .net 4, let alone 4.5 or 4.8.

I use the one from the ajaxtoolkit. The tool kit is free, open source, and is now maintained by the great folks from DevExpress.

You can find it here:

https://www.devexpress.com/Products/AJAX-Control-Toolkit/

And like a lot of such up-loaders, they even have a hot spot on the web page (supports drag + drop).

So, the aj one looks like this:

[image]

And not only does the user see a progress bar, but they can easy add more files, remove files, and even a VERY nice cancel option exists to stop a upload (and being ajax, it responds instant to a user cancel of a upload).

As noted, since these up-loaders send up the file in chunks, then the only practical limit to upload size is your disk drive size.

A good solid, high quality file uploader should be part of any developers tool box.

As noted, there are good number of choices in this area for these types of file uploaders, and a good number are even free. And as above shows, they allow un-limited file sizes.

Even better, they also tend to not over load the server, since one browser post-back with a "huge" file tends to really swamp the server anyway, and often users will think their browser has frozen.

These "ajax" file up-loaders thus by breaking up the file into little chunks not only play nice with the server (don't use a lot of memory), but bite sized chunks being up-loaded allows a progress bar, and better the end result is no real limits on the file size

Comment: Your reply helped me looking into other directions. I have implemented the ajaxuploadfile and I was able to load small files.  I need to check larger files.

Comment: There are additional settings you probably will need for this to work. For example, you have to set the AjaxFileUpLoad MaxFileSize to -1. I would also increase the Chunk size to 8192, or even 16000, as that will double or triple the up-load speed.